# Comparing pandas timestamps of different resolutions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have two time series data frames (~45k rows versus 5 rows). One has timestamps down to milliseconds and the other down to seconds. I want to create a new column in the larger dataframe such that:
a) a value is appended to the row in the larger dataframe whose timestamp is closest (in seconds) to the timestamps in the smaller dataframe
b) NaN for any other timestamp.

```
larger df = 
            timestamp           price
0       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 1
1       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 1
2       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 2
3       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 4
4       2018-04-24 06:01:02.775 2
5       2018-04-24 06:01:02.825 3
6       2018-04-24 06:01:03.050 5
7       2018-04-24 06:01:03.125 6
8       2018-04-24 06:01:03.275 7
9       2018-04-24 06:01:03.300 4
10      2018-04-24 06:01:03.300 3
11      2018-04-24 06:01:03.950 5
12      2018-04-24 06:01:04.050 5


smaller df = 
   timestamp           price
0   24/04/2018 06:01:02 2
1   24/04/2018 12:33:37 4   
2   24/04/2018 14:29:34 5   
3   24/04/2018 15:02:50 6   
4   24/04/2018 15:20:04 7   

desired df =

            timestamp       price  newCol
0       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 1   aValue
1       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 1   NaN
2       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 2   NaN
3       2018-04-24 06:01:02.600 4   NaN
4       2018-04-24 06:01:02.775 2   NaN
5       2018-04-24 06:01:02.825 3   NaN
6       2018-04-24 06:01:03.050 5   NaN
7       2018-04-24 06:01:03.125 6   NaN
8       2018-04-24 06:01:03.275 7   NaN
9       2018-04-24 06:01:03.300 4   NaN
10      2018-04-24 06:01:03.300 3   NaN
11      2018-04-24 06:01:03.950 5   NaN
12      2018-04-24 06:01:04.050 5   NaN
```

Your help will be very much appreciated. I am still too new to programming in general to solve this easily.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### `reindex`

In order to only use the values once, I had to track the timestamp from the smaller dataframe.  So I include those values when I `reindex` with `'nearest'`.  I then use `duplicated` within a mask.

```
df_small_new = df_small.set_index('timestamp', drop=False)
df_small_new = df_small_new.reindex(df_large.timestamp, method='nearest')


df_large.assign(
    newcol=df_small_new.price.mask(df_small_new.timestamp.duplicated()).values)

                 timestamp  price  newcol
0  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      1     2.0
1  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      1     NaN
2  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      2     NaN
3  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      4     NaN
4  2018-04-24 06:01:02.775      2     NaN
5  2018-04-24 06:01:02.825      3     NaN
6  2018-04-24 06:01:03.050      5     NaN
7  2018-04-24 06:01:03.125      6     NaN
8  2018-04-24 06:01:03.275      7     NaN
9  2018-04-24 06:01:03.300      4     NaN
10 2018-04-24 06:01:03.300      3     NaN
11 2018-04-24 06:01:03.950      5     NaN
12 2018-04-24 06:01:04.050      5     NaN
```

---

#### [**`pandas.merge_asof`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

- Rename the `'price'` column in the small dataframe
- Make sure to set the `direction` to be `'nearest'`
- This almost answers the question

---

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df_large,
    df_small.rename(columns={'price': 'newcol'}),
    on='timestamp', direction='nearest'
)

                 timestamp  price  newcol
0  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      1       2
1  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      1       2
2  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      2       2
3  2018-04-24 06:01:02.600      4       2
4  2018-04-24 06:01:02.775      2       2
5  2018-04-24 06:01:02.825      3       2
6  2018-04-24 06:01:03.050      5       2
7  2018-04-24 06:01:03.125      6       2
8  2018-04-24 06:01:03.275      7       2
9  2018-04-24 06:01:03.300      4       2
10 2018-04-24 06:01:03.300      3       2
11 2018-04-24 06:01:03.950      5       2
12 2018-04-24 06:01:04.050      5       2
```

Comment: Hi piRSquared,thanks for the quick response. How would I go about ensuring that I don't have repeated values in newCol though? Ideally newCol will only show a value on the first row and NaN for the rest. I could even live with the same value being shown (in this case '2') when the seconds timestamps are the same

Comment: Oh, you only want to use that value once?  I didn't see that.  Give me a moment